# Coding Approach - Spawning items in escape game

Tags: algorithm, game-development

This question is not language specific as i am essentially looking for the algorithm used.

So for those who dont know there is a escape game called Granny 2 where there are pre-defined places where items (utility, consumables, keys) spawns. the keys unlock other parts of map or locked container which contain further items.

Now, how to implement this that which item goes where procedurally without making a dead end? say the key to box 1 in in box 2 and the key to box 2 is in box 1. we need at least 1 key out first.

What my thought is we assign the items (to be spawned) a lockLevel variable and same for the spawn points. lockLevel = 0 means out in open, 1 means behind 1 lock and so on. and then we can randomly assign items of certain lockLevel to places of that certian lockLevel.

But this is very crude and games like Granny 2 surely use a more complex algorithm. Can you please tell me how to approach this???

Comment: My guess is that directed graphs might be helpful here. If getting to B required holding something in place A, then place an edge going from A to B. After all items are placed, check the graph. If you cannot find a path from the starting node to all other nodes, there are areas in the game that cannot be reached.

Comment: you want to design the `level` or solve it ?

Comment: @vin i want to design the level and want to do it procedurally.

Comment: @user2212559 hmmm that is a good approach but it seems to be resource intensive as we are checking for all the node combinations of different places, items and locks. i will try to use it first and then try to multithread it. thank you.

Comment: @PriyanshYadav I would then say describe the universe as a network and solve for the flow in it. And you can add nodes / remove nodes until you have  solution